# Suggested character set for non utf8 columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, guid

Currently I'm using `VARCHAR`/`TEXT` with `utf8_general_ci` for all character columns in mysql. Now I want to improve database layout/performance.

What I figured out so far is to better use

- `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` for fixed length columns as GUIDs or session ids
- also use `CHAR` for small columns having length of 1 or maybe 2?

As I do not want to go as wide to save my GUIDs as `BINARY(16)` because of handling issues, I'd rather save them as `CHAR(32)` to especially improve keys. (I would even save 2/3 when switching from utf8 to some 1-byte-charset)

- So what will the best character set be for such columns? ASCII? latin1? BINARY? Which collation?
- What characterset/collation to use for other columns where I do not need utf8 support but need proper sorting. A Binary would fail?

Is it good practice to mix up different character sets in same mysql (innodb) table? Or do I get better performance when all columns have same charset within same table? Or even database?

Comment: UTF-8 only uses more than one byte if the character falls outside the ASCII range. Stringified UUID's (if that's what you're using as GUID) always fall within that range.

Comment: @robertklep I heard that and it makes sense, but I think this does not apply to index (space consumption)!? Eg a `EXPLAIN SELECT` shows up a 2/3 smaller `key_len` value when converting utf8 column to latin1

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider that (I don't know a lot about how MySQL/InnoDB indexes are implemented).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GUID/UUID/MD5/SHA1 are all hex and dash.  For them

```
CHAR(..) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci
```

That will allow for `A`=`a` when comparing hex strings.

For Base64 things, use either of

```
CHAR(..) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin
BINARY(..)
```

since `A` is *not* semantically the same as `a`.

Further notes...

- utf8 spits at you if you give it an invalid 8-bit value.
- ascii spits at you for any 8-bit value.
- latin1 accepts anything -- thereby your problems down the road
- It is quite OK to have different columns in a table having different charsets and/or collations.
- The charset/collation on the table is just a *default*, ripe for overriding at the column definition.
- `BINARY` may be a tiny bit faster than any `_bin` collation, but not enough to notice.
- Use `CHAR` for columns that are truly fixed length; don't mislead the user by using it for other cases.
- `%_bin` is faster than `%_general_ci`, which is faster than other collations.  Again, you would be hard-pressed to measure a difference.
- Never use `TINYTEXT` or `TINYBLOB`.
- For proper encoding, use the appropriate charset.
- For "proper sorting", use the appropriate collation.  See example below.
- For "proper sorting" where multiple languages are represented, and you are using `utf8mb4`, use `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` (or `utf8mb4_900_ci` if using version 8.0).  The 520 and 900 refer to Unicode standards; new collations are likely to come in the future.

If you are entirely in Czech, then consider these charsets and collations.  I list them in preferred order:

```
mysql> show collation like '%czech%';
+------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation        | Charset | Id  | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| utf8mb4_czech_ci | utf8mb4 | 234 |         | Yes      |       8 | -- opens up the world
| utf8_czech_ci    | utf8    | 202 |         | Yes      |       8 | -- opens up most of the world
| latin2_czech_cs  | latin2  |   2 |         | Yes      |       4 | -- kinda like latin1
```

The rest are "useless":

```
| cp1250_czech_cs  | cp1250  |  34 |         | Yes      |       2 |
| ucs2_czech_ci    | ucs2    | 138 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf16_czech_ci   | utf16   | 111 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf32_czech_ci   | utf32   | 170 |         | Yes      |       8 |
+------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**More**

- The reason for using smaller datatypes (where appropriate) is to shrink the dataset, which leads to less I/O, which leads to things being more cacheable, which makes the program run faster.  This is especially important for huge datasets; it is less important for small- or medium-sized datasets.
- `ENUM` is 1 byte, yet acts like a string.  So you get the "best of both worlds".  (There are drawbacks, and there is a 'religious war' among advocates for `ENUM` vs `TINYINT` vs `VARCHAR`.)
- Usually columns that are "short" are always the same length.  A `country_code` is always 2 letters, always ascii, always could benefit from case insensitive collation.  So `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci` is optimal.  If you have something that is sometimes 1-char, sometimes 2, then flip a coin; whatever you do won't make much difference.
- `VARCHAR` (up to 255) has an extra 1-byte length attached to it.  So, if your strings vary in length *at all*, `VARCHAR` is at least as good as `CHAR`.  So simplify your brain processing:  "variable length --> `VARCHAR".
- `BIT`, depending on version, may be implemented as a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.  If you have only a few bits in your table, it is not worth worrying about.
- One of my [*Rules of Thumb*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots) says that if you aren't likely to get a 10% improvement, move on to some other optimization.  Much of what we are discussing here is under 10% (space in this case).  Still, get in the habit of thinking about it when writing `CREATE TABLE`.  I often see tables with `BIGINT` and `DOUBLE` (each 8 bytes) that could easily use smaller columns.  Sometimes saving more than 50% (space).
- How does "space" translate into "speed".  Tiny tables -> a tiny percentage.  Huge tables -> In some cases 10x.  (That's 10-fold, not 10%.)  (UUIDs are one way to get really bad performance on huge tables.)

**ENUM**

- Acts and feels like a string, yet takes only one byte.  (One byte translates, indirectly, into a slight speed improvement.)
- Practical when fewer than, say, 10 different values.
- Impractical if frequently adding a new value -- requires `ALTER TABLE`, though it *can* be "inplace".
- Suggest starting the list with `'unknown'` (or something like that) and making the column `NOT NULL` (versus `NULL`).
- The character set for the enum needs to be whatever is otherwise being used for the connection.  The choice does not matter much unless you have options that *collate* equal (eg, `A` versus `a`).

Comment: thanks a lot! does it make sense to use smaller integers (<4B) and bit? I heared that mysqls `ENUM` is good practice to use? what about CHAR(1) and (2) columns? use VARCHAR instead when some (which percentage?) are not filled?

Comment: I like `ENUM` in some situations; some people dislike them.  I oppose `CHAR` _except_ for truly fixed-length columns; and then only with the appropriate `CHARACTER SET` (which is _usually_ `ascii`).

Comment: thanks @rick but this is not really useful as you do not state why you 'like' enum (pros/cons) and we already know the mentioned stuff about chars. Maybe you can explain why/when to use `ENUM` makes sense (esp. performance relevant) and if it makes still sense to use `CHAR` when many/some rows (percentage?) have no value in that column.

Comment: @toshniba - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46693197/1766831  (and others)