# Best way to manage master data in google cloud sql (mysql) db tables vs enum columns

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, google-cloud-sql

My project has many master data (for eg: status, locales, devices etc). To store master data, I see following options

1. Use Enum columns in mysql. The issue is, every time a new entry is added, the table has to be altered. Getting a list of values in the enum is not straight forward.
2. Create tables for each master data and maintain a foreign key reference.
3. Just store it as strings in the mysql table. And manage the master data as an enum in the code or even store it in a Cloud Datastore (for ease of manipulation)

What's the best way. If there other good options, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to discuss the merits (and drawbacks) of ENUMs...

**ENUM**

- An ENUM takes 1 byte (2 if you have > 255 possible values).
- You should specify all the possible values when the CREATE TABLE.
- Later you can ALTER TABLE to add new values to an ENUM.  Running it (on recent versions of MySQL) is "cheap" *if* you only add new options on the *end* of the list.
- As with all datatypes, an `ENUM` column could be NULL or NOT NULL. If you make it `NULLable`, an extra bit is needed (elsewhere) to hold that
  info. And you need to think about what "NULL" should mean in your
  app.  Instead, I recommend using `NOT NULL` and making the first option be whatever you would have meant by `NULL`.
- If you did index the ENUM, it still might not be used. `WHERE my_enum = 'something'` is unlikely to use an index on my_enum unless
  'something' occurs in less than 10-30% of the rows. (I can't give you
  an exact number -- the optimizer has a mind of its own. Switching
  from using an index to doing a table scan is usually "the right
  thing" when the indexed value is 'too' common.)

**VARCHAR**

- `VARCHAR(77)` that contains `abcde` occupies 1+5 bytes -- 1 for the length, 5 for the actual characters.  (Etc)

**Lookup Table**

- Have a 2 column table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` and a `VARCHAR`.
- Index each column.
- Write code to add a new column for each new value.
- Use `JOIN` to get the string from the id.
- The `id` would probably be a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (values 0..255), so it is as compact as `ENUM`.
- Consider whether you might need `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (0..65535).
- This may be best if the options are likely to grow a lot.
- Beware of `INSERT IGNORE` -- it may burn `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids, and quickly exceed 255.

**Comments**

- All variants can handle a string, but some are more complicated (`JOIN`) than others.
- `VARCHAR` is the most costly in disk space.
- In *some* situations the extra-table case can be quite costly due to the extra `JOIN`.

Armed with these pros and cons, you decide.  There is no "one best way".